# Using jQuery and/or AJAX to pull current images from a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was tasked to use a Wikipedia API to retrieve images from the New Jersey website, and I came up with two ways to do similar tasks. The first way was to use a JSON, but it pulled the whole page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=New_Jersey&prop=text&format=json&callback=?', function(json) { 
$('#wikiInfo').html(json.parse.text['*']); 
$("#wikiInfo").find("a:not(.references a)").attr("href", function(){ return "http://www.wikipedia.org" + $(this).attr("href");}); 
$("#wikiInfo").find("a").attr("target", "_blank"); 
});
</script>

<div id="wikiInfo">&nbsp;</div>
```

And I also used an AJAX request paired with jQuery, but it pulled only the text.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&page=New_Jersey&callback=?",
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
    var i = $('<div></div>').html(markup);

    // remove links as they will not work
    i.find('a').each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); });

    // remove any references
    i.find('sup').remove();

    // remove cite error
    i.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();

    $('#article').html($(i).find('p'));


    },
    error: function (errorMessage) {
    }
});    

});
```

Which way is best to approach this problem, and how can I fix it to pull only the current images, as well as attribute the username to each picture?

Thanks!

Comment: So I did it, but the pictures weren't loading on my page. The pictures definitely were there though. When I ran my debugger and checked the console, it pulled up the error SCRIPT7002: XMLHTTPError : 0x2. Any quick way to fix that?

Comment: Make sure that images you're working on are not relative path. Certainly, only absolute/full paths will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to get images is using [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

**ES6 version:**

```
$.getJSON('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=New_Jersey&prop=text&format=json&callback=?', function(json) { 
const text = json.parse.text['*'];
const regex = /([-\w+\.\/]+(?:png|svg))/gmi;
let m;
while ((m = regex.exec(text)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    console.log(`Found match: ${m[1]}`);
}});
```

**ES5 version:**

```
$.getJSON('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=New_Jersey&prop=text&format=json&callback=?', function(json) { 
var text = json.parse.text['*'];
var regex = /([-\w+\.\/]+(?:png|svg))/gmi;
var m;
while ((m = regex.exec(text)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    console.log('Found match: ' + m[1]);
}});
```